# Be careful with edit summaries!

Tags: discussion, moderation, editing

For a while, I've been planning to write a series here (MMSE.Meta) about tips on how to get along well with people in the SE network (which can be hard at times, when people are very passionate!).

Recently I saw some drama on a different SE site and had some thoughts I'd like to share! This got me writing the first part of this series a bit earlier than I otherwise would have.

I want to point out that questions, answers, and comments can all be deleted, or even edited, but edit summaries cannot! So if you get very angry at someone, and when editing their post you make an ***accusation***, or an ***insult***, you won't be able to change it later if you regret it! Even users with 25,000 rep, and even diamond moderators can't change edit summaries! I'm not even sure if Community Managers can, though developers might be able to, but it's extremely hard to compete for their attention.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33699865)'s an example of what I think is a good edit summary when changing a full-form URL to a hyperlink:

[image]

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33684804)'s another one:

[image]

A bad one in my opinion would be something like:

> "I'm removing your repeated nonsense. You've done this so many times and it needs to stop."

Another bad one in my opinion would be something like:

> "You are harassing me, so I'm deleting this"

In the second case, it's better to let the edit summary just explain precisely what you're doing: "deleting the second sentence because it's not needed in the answer in my opinion" or perhaps "deleting the second sentence, please see this Meta post for further explanation."

For dealing with harassment, it would be much better to talk things out in chat, private flags, maybe even comments, rather than in an edit summary. Wikipedia might have done a better job than SE in [explaining the need to be careful about accusations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Harassment#Accusing_others_of_harassment): "Making accusations of harassment can be inflammatory and hence these accusations may not be helpful in a dispute. It can be seen as a personal attack if harassment is alleged without clear evidence that the others' action is actually harassment, and unfounded accusations may constitute harassment themselves if done repeatedly. The result is often accusations of harassment on your part, which tends to create a nasty cycle. At the same time, claims of harassment should be taken seriously and not be summarily dismissed unless it becomes clear the accusations are not well-founded." **Regardless** of whether or not you think your comment/accusation is appropriate:

### Remembering that you cannot go back and change edit summaries later, can save you from a lot of future trouble!

Comment: Moderators can edit the comments.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I didn't know that! By "comments" do you mean the part next to "Edit summary"? That's helpful to know, and I'll edit my post accordingly if so.